# Crystal lang, type of type

Tags: crystal-lang

How i can define type for other types, modules, classes. For example:

```
module One
end

module Two
end

array_of_modules = Array(?).new
array_of_modules << One
array_of_modules << Two
```

Or for classes

```
array_of_types = Array(?).new
array_of_types << String
array_of_types << Int32
array_of_types << MyClassName
```

Answer (score 3):

Generically this is not (yet) possible with Crystal.

If you know all the possible types upfront you could define a union however:

```
types = [] of String.class|Int32.class
types << String
types << Int32
pp types # => [String, Int32]
```

Admittedly that's not very useful though. That's why when talking about modules and classes that you or your users control a common workaround is to use some kind of marker module:

```
module Base
end

module Foo
  extend Base
end

class Bar
  extend Base
end

types = [] of Base
types << Foo
types << Bar
pp types # => [Foo, Bar]
```

Lastly another common approach is to use the macro `ArrayLiteral#<<` which doesn't come with type restrictions but of course is limited to compile time setup of your configuration and has many other restrictions, so a very concrete solution would be very highly dependent on your usecase.

```
{% begin %}
{% types = [] of Nil # Dummy type, could be whatever
   types << Foo
   types << Bar %}
pp {{types}} # => [Foo, Bar]
{% end %}
```

Comment: Thanks, i understood. I will use the parent module and generics for it.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, it is not possible, as `Array(Class)` is not supported in Crystal.

The types in your example (e.g. `One.class`, `String.class`, `Int32.class`, `MyClassName.class`) are `Class` that is why I believe you would need `Array(Class)`. But depending on your use case, there might be other ways to express it.

Comment: Thanks, yes, it is really not impossible. I will change my way of realization.